# List decomposition using case classes and extractor objects

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have created a list as below

```
List (1, 2, 3, 4)
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

With this, if I do pattern matching as below

```
res4 match {
     case ::(head, tail) => println (head); println(tail);
     }
```

gives me:

```
1
List(2, 3, 4)
```

which is expected. Next, if I try the following as an extractor object

```
(::)(2, List(3, 4))
```

gives me:

```
res6: scala.collection.immutable.::[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

No problems so far. Next, If I try the following:

```
res4 match {
  case :+(head, tail) => println (head); println(tail);
}
```

I get

```
List(1, 2, 3)
4
```

Still no problems. Now, If try the :+ extractor object, the following way:

```
(:+)(List(1, 2), 3)
```

I get the following error:

```
<console>:12: error: scala.collection.:+.type does not take parameters
   (:+)(List(1, 2), 3)
```

What could be the issue here? Is there no :+ extractor object defined ? If no, then how come it works inside the pattern matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the issue here? Is there no :+ extractor object defined
>   ? If no, then how come it works inside the pattern matching?

The problem is that the `:+` object supports an `unapply` method, which is what is used for the Extractor Pattern to work in pattern matching, but doesn't support an `apply` method:

```
/** An extractor used to init/last deconstruct sequences. */
object :+ {
  /** Splits a sequence into init :+ tail.
   * @return Some((init, tail)) if sequence is non-empty. None otherwise.
   */
  def unapply[T,Coll <: SeqLike[T, Coll]](
      t: Coll with SeqLike[T, Coll]): Option[(Coll, T)] =
    if(t.isEmpty) None
    else Some(t.init -> t.last)
}
```

Hence, you get a compile time error. When you think about it, this makes sense, what should be the result of a `:+` apply?

Comment: Thanks Yuval. Yes, ( :+) apply complains about apply not being a member. I should have checked that.